# Loading results of PHP function into DIV container

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It seems this question has been answered in the past, however, I'm either 1) having a hard time grasping the solutions or 2) not implementing them correctly.

I have a PHP function, that when run, will return results of a database query.  Results look similar to this:

```
<a href="http://www.dannychoo.com/post/en/26468/Koenji.html" class="danny-choo">Koenji</a>
```

I can echo this into a page just fine.  What I'd like to do is give an end user the option to refresh the link (which can be done by refreshing the page and echoing a new random string returned by the php function) without having to refresh the whole page. I've tried a few different methods, but it seems the function that returns the  element is only run when the page reloads - so my URL never changes.

Here is my latest attempt.  I figured the url I'm grabbing from the database was only getting set when the paged loaded.  I thought setting a function to initialize the url variable would help - no good.  It still only works once on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateVariable();
    $('#dannychoolink').html(random + url);
    $('.danny-choo').attr('target', '_blank');
});

$('#clicky').click(function() {
    updateVariable();
    $('#dannychoolink').html(random + url);
    $('.danny-choo').attr('target', '_blank');
});

function updateVariable() {
    url = '<?php echo dannyChoo();?>';
    random = 'Random DannyChoo.com article:  ';
};
```

You can see it live at www.dannychoofan.com.

Any help is appreciated =0)

Comment: If you want this to happen without refreshing the page, you'll need to use AJAX (javascript) to call your php function. Take a look at the [Jquery ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), they should give you a point in the right direction. Also, there are tons of really really good tutorials out there, just give it a google, but more importantly give it a shot yourself, and if you have any problems come back for some help. :)

Comment: Thanks - I've honestly exhausted my Google goggles :P.  I've used ajax calls to send post data to my function - but the results returned are always empty.  Does my function need to do more than 'return results'?  Post them to a global variable for my page to grab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your looking for an ajax style call.

You should put the contents of the dannyChoo() function into a new file called articleLinkGenerator.php at the same level as your index.php file. This file should have the contents of the dannyChoo() function so that it automatically executes and echos the html you are expecting for the link like

```
<?php
    function dannyChoo(){
        // generate random link code
        echo $random_link_html // Like <a href="http://www.dannychoo.com/post/en/26468/Koenji.html" class="danny-choo">Koenji</a>
     }

      dannyChoo();
```

Then in your index.php (main web site) update your functions using ajax(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)  to look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateVariable();
});

$('#clicky').click(function() {
    updateVariable();

});

function updateVariable() {
    $.get('articleLinkGenerator.php',function(data){
        $('#dannychoolink').html(data);
     });
};
```

Comment: Michael - thanks!  This sort of works.  I'm not sure why, but the data isn't being output to the correct div (it's actually sitting above the <head> tags 0.o.)  Also, is there a way I can send a session variable (in case a script holds multiple functions and I want to switch based on session data.)

Comment: Never mind - ended up getting it working.  Thanks my friend!  I thought I'd never get this one ^^;

Answer (score 0):

It's because PHP runs before the page loads, and JavaScript runs after the page loads, so your variable never changes without another page load.